# ERROR : undefined is not an object (evaluation 'style.width')

Tags: javascript, image, react-native, undefined, imagebackground

Hello everyone I'm having trouble with  component and I get an undefined error message.So my app has 2 screen,the first one has a list of imagebackgrounds and when you press on one of the images you get a description of that image on another screen.So on this second screen I get the image that I pressed on in an image component (not background).
The problem I'm having is that when I save I get the undefined error.

***First screen component :***

```
const MealItems = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.main}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onSelectMeal}>
        <View>
          <View style={{ ...styles.details, ...styles.maintitle }}>
            <ImageBackground
              //resizeMode={"center"}
              source={{ uri: props.image }}
              style={styles.imagebg}
            >
              <View style={styles.textContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.title} numberOfLines={1}>
                  {props.title}
                </Text>
              </View>
            </ImageBackground>
          </View>

          <View style={{ ...styles.details, ...styles.info }}>
            <Text>{props.duration}</Text>
            <Text>{props.complexity.toUpperCase()}</Text>
            <Text>{props.affordability.toUpperCase()}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

styles = StyleSheet.create({
  main: {
    height: 200,
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "#f5f5f5",
    borderRadius: 20,
    overflow: "hidden",
    marginVertical: 10,
  },

  maintitle: {
    height: "85%",
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: "white",
    textAlign: "center",
  },
  details: {
    flexDirection: "row",
  },
  imagebg: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
  },
  info: {
    backgroundColor: "gray",
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    alignItems: "center",
    height: "15%",
  },
  textContainer: {
    paddingHorizontal: 12,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.3)",
  },
});

export default MealItems;

***Second screen file:***
const howToCook = (props) => {
  const availableMeals = useSelector((state) => state.Meals.filteredMeals);
  const mealId = props.navigation.getParam("mealId");
  const selectedMeal = availableMeals.find((meal) => mealId === meal.id);

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <Image source={{ uri: selectedMeal.imageUrl }} style={styles.image} />
      <View style={styles.textDetail}>
        <Text>{selectedMeal.duration}</Text>
        <Text>{selectedMeal.complexity.toUpperCase()}</Text>
        <Text>{selectedMeal.affordability.toUpperCase()}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.titlePlace}>
        <Text style={styles.textTitle}>Ingredients</Text>
      </View>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. If you want us to help you, please give us the informations we need. Do you have an error? Show us the errormessage.
What did you try to solve the problem? What did not work?

Comment: Your program is incomplete please add more code snippets like the one in question does not use style.width. To fix the error you can check if your style.width is defined or not. Apparently, you're using styles but using style.width. So check if it's styles.width or style.width.

Comment: Thank you for your response.The problem is coming from the node_modules generated by expo.Please find the code that is being used by expo for 
<ImageBackground>.
The code : 
<Image
          {...props}
          style={[
            StyleSheet.absoluteFill,
            {
           
             width: style.width,
              height: style.height,
            },
            imageStyle,
          ]}
          ref={imageRef}
        />

Comment: If it's possible I would like to have a little chat with you so I could explain in details.I really need some help . -Rohit.